# Nuxt .js and Laravel API - CSRF token mismatch

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, session-cookies, csrf, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to make a login page using nuxt.js as Front-end and Laravel for the API.

Unfortunately, after I take the csrf token from sanctum-cookie, I can't use it because of "CSRF token mismatch." I don't know what to do from here.

Laravel info:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8080
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=http://localhost:8000,localhost:3000,localhost:8000,http://localhost:3000
```

8080 is the port for LAravel and 3000 is nuxt.

Those are the calls to the api and the login is returning an error about CSRF and I have no idea why.

```
// calls from nuxt
async function validate() {

  await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/sanctum/csrf-cookie', {
    withCredentials: true
  });

  const token = useCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');

  await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/login', {
    'email': 'email@example.com',
    'password': '1234567890'
  }, {
    headers: {
      'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token.value as string
    }
  })
}
```

cors.php config

```
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:3000')],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days ... all i need to do was to add `withCredentials: true` for the login axios...

Awesome! <3

Answer (score 0):

set sanctumn.php :

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8080,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),
```

then set env variable in .env file as given below:

```
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
ROOT_URL=//127.0.0.1:8080
APP_URL=http://localhost
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost
```

then run these commands in laravel project:

```
php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan optimize && php artisan serve
```

then in your nuxt login.vue:

```
async function validate() {

  await useFetch("http://localhost:8080/sanctum/csrf-cookie", {
    credentials: "include",
  });

  const token = useCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');

  await useFetch("http://localhost:8080/api/login", {
    credentials: "include",
    method: "POST",
    body: {
      'email': 'email',
      'password': 'password'
    },
    headers: {
      'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token.value as string,
    },
    watch: false
  })
// remaining codes...
}
```